# Error building a public Shopify app: ngrok.io refused to connect

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I want a public and NOT embedded Shopify app. This app is a sales channel, which imports products from Shopify stores to my e-commerce website. The stores which install the app will have their products listed on my e-commerce website.

---

I have built the initial steps to install the app and import the products into my e-commerce website.

Now when user clicks on the app icon, I want him to be redirected to the following page which displays the list of imported product:

```
https://my-commerce.com/products?storeurl=perisn-handcrafts.myshopify.com
```

If the above links returns a list of product as below, the product list will be displayed within the Shopify Admin cosole:

```
<table data-toggle="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>UniqueThirdPartyProductCode</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>ImageUrl</th>
            <th>CombinedCategoryViewModel</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>39-4477334519894</td>
            <td>Blue</td>
            <td>550.00</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>"todo"</td>
        </tr>

        /* more data... */

    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

But if I put the table inside the page layout, which adds `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tag to the result, then the result is not displayed... for example if my app return the following HTML:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <table data-toggle="table">
    /* 
     * content of the table 
     */
    </table>
</body>
```

I would get this result:

[image]

I am not sure why I am getting this error:

> ngrok.io refused to connect

Also it seems like my app is embedded within Shopify admin console, is it possible to build a public app which is not embedded?

Comment: The error you are showing is more related to ngrok connection or your http response (which might be an error code). I would suggest checking the ngrok output on your machine first as it might lead you on the best direction (check you see the requests coming in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated Answer

My Shopify app is a Sales Channel and Shopify requires all Sales Channels to be embedded within the admin console ([I learnt this the hard way](https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-APIs-SDKs/Are-all-public-apps-embedded-in-Shopify-Console/m-p/830007))

In order to make the app embedded inside Shopify admin console we need to remove `X-Frame-Options` header from response. My application which is developed in ASP.NET MVC and I have added the following code to Global.asax to remove the said header (note that removing `X-Frame-Options` expose our website to [clickjacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking) attack, so remove the header just for this specific purpose):

**Global.asax**

```
protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders()
{
    var routeValues = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values;
    if (routeValues.ContainsKey("controller"))
    {
        // make sure you only remove the header for a very specific use case
        if (string.Equals((string)routeValues["controller"], "EmbeddedShopifyController", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            Response.Headers.Remove("X-Frame-Options");
        }
    }
}
```

### Original answer

The reason for this error was that I had configured my app to be embedded. To check if your app is embedded or not, go to your Shopify Partners page:

*Apps -> Extensions -> Embedded app*

[image]

Click on *Manage embedded app* button, and here you can see if the app is configured to be embedded or not. You can Enable/Disable this setting.

In my case, I disabled the embedded app configuration and my app now works fine.